# How to compare arrays in Qt unit testing

Tags: c++, unit-testing, qt

I have to compare my expected array and the array that is being generated by calling my function. I know that this is a simple question but as i am new to Qt, could any one help me with this. My code is

```
void TesterClass::testevolve()
{
    float T[100][100],A[100][100];
    A[0][0]=0;
    A[0][1]=75;
    A[0][2]=75;
    A[0][3]=75;
    A[0][4]=0;
    A[1][0]=0;
    A[1][1]=42.857;
    A[1][2]=63.169;
    A[1][4]=30;
    A[2][0]=0;
    A[2][1]=33.258;
    A[2][3]=76.116;
    A[2][4]=30;
    A[3][0]=0;
    A[3][1]=33.928;
    A[3][2]=52.455;
    A[3][3]=69.642;
    A[3][4]=30;
    A[4][0]=0;
    A[4][1]=50;
    A[4][2]=50;
    A[4][4]=0;

    ClassInitiate ci;
    ClassOutput co;
    int i,j;
    float c[100][100]=ci.initializeArray(T[100][100]);
    co.output(c[100][100]);
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            QVERIFY2(A[i][j]==c[i][j], "evolving array failed");
        }
    }
}
```

I know there is something wrong with this test case. Can anyone tell me the right way of writing this.

Comment: Please explain the problem you're having.

Comment: i dont know how to write a test case for comparing two arrays in Qt unit test

Comment: Explain the problem you have _with that piece of code_. What is it doing/not doing? Is it compiling, if not, what is the error? If it runs, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

QCOMPARE just compare pointers values, not the arrays elements values:

```
FAIL!  : SC_tests::testSeemCarving() Compared pointers are not the same
Actual (array): 0x93c6168
Expected (array1): 0x92d9a50
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily do this with raw memory C arrays -- you should wrap them in some kind of class that implements the `==` operator.

If you can't do that, then what you have now is probably the best you're going to get.